# Jmeter extracting response using JSON Path

Tags: api, jmeter, response, extract, jsonpath

Hi Can someone help me simulate this scenario, Example this is the response I got, I want to extract all alertId with the name parameter contains **test**. You response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Response:

[
{
"duplicateCount": 0,
"fqdn": "qa-ubuntu14-4",
"appName": "TEST_APD_UB14",
"stateString": "OPEN",
"category": "FILESCAN",
"alkey": {
"agentId": "8470ea64-a710-3e46-ba6b-ccd37ebc4074",
"role": "AD SERVER",
"alertId": "0258a7ca-bc72-3a53-aa98-3098c87411ba",
"id": "6695a7fa-ab9f-43fa-871b-620cd1eeb75054af7770-604b-11e9-b486-8d59ab9344597cea0ea2-d897-3696-852d-5f3cb36f270e8470ea64-a710-3e46-ba6b-ccd37ebc4074/var/log/test321.txttest321.txtA",
"applicationContextId": "7cea0ea2-d897-3696-852d-5f3cb36f270e"
},
"properties": {
"name": "test321.txt",
"acl": ""
}
},
{
"duplicateCount": 0,
"fqdn": "qa-ubuntu14-4",
"appName": "TEST_APD_UB18",
"stateString": "OPEN",
"category": "FILESCAN",
"alkey": {
"agentId": "8470ea64-a710-3e46-ba6b-ccd37ebc4074",
"role": "AD SERVER",
"alertId": "0258a7ca-bc72-3a53-aa98-3098c8741CDA",
"id": "6695a7fa-ab9f-43fa-871b-620cd1eeb75054af7770-604b-11e9-b486-8d59ab9344597cea0ea2-d897-3696-852d-5f3cb36f270e8470ea64-a710-3e46-ba6b-ccd37ebc4074/var/log/test321.txttest321.txtA",
"applicationContextId": "7cea0ea2-d897-3696-852d-5f3cb36f270e"
},
"properties": {
"name": "test555.txt",
"acl": ""
}
}
]

Screenshot:
[image]

Expected Result:
I want to extract all alertId with the name parameter contains **test**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following JSON query to extract the values:

```
[*].[?(@.properties.name contains 'test')]alkey.agentId
```

I found this reference with [JSON Path Syntax](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) is really useful.